# LevelHelper : destroy and recreate physics body

Tags: box2d, levelhelper

Using LH with cocos2d and Box2d

I have a ball (dynamic body) which goes out of the screen.

I would like to destroy and recreate it, placing it back in its initial position.

Without LevelHelper, I would do it via destroyBody and createBody.

How do I do it with LevelHelper?

Answer (score 0):

you just make copy of the lhsprite object of ball before destroying and later to recreate ball just add copied lhsprite object to your layer.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler answer would be

LHSprite *sprite ;//(let us assume this is your sprite)
CCPoint originalPos = sprite->getPosition();

if(sprite->position is out of screen){
    sprite->getBody->setTransform(b2vec2(originalPos.x/PTM_RATIO, originalPos.y/PTM_RATIO),0);
}

Simple. Hope this helps :)